# How to use update statement to update a column with value of another existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a table `TB_ACCOUNT (ACCT_KEY, ACCT_NUM, CLEAN_ACCT_KEY, CLEAN_ACCT_NUM)`. `ACCT_KEY` and `ACCT_NUM` are having garbage value. I need to write an update statement to update each row value in `ACCT_KEY` with value in `CLEAN_ACCT_KEY` and value in `ACCT_NUM` with value in `CLEAN_ACCT_NUM`. There is no unique constraint on any column.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
UPDATE TB_ACCOUNT SET ACCT_KEY = CLEAN_ACCT_KEY, ACCT_NUM = CLEAN_ACCT_NUM
```

This query will, row-for-row, set the value in the columns to the value from the corresponding `CLEAN`_ columns.